# I am having trouble understanding Node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble understanding this Node.js code:

I understand importation of the module 'express' and using the Router constructor.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, I don't understand the purpose of '/', 'index' in the following part:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's the URL the route is for, read the documentation.

Comment: / is an indicator for any language that just shows the route to the folder the script is running in. It's the same thing as typing in the full path to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

The function of 'index' is that it defines which view to render

```
 res.render(view, [locals], callback)
```

The function of '/' can be explained by

```
// invoked for any requested passed to this router
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
// .. some logic here .. like any other middleware
next();
});

// will handle any request that ends in /events
// depends on where the router is "use()'d"
router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
// ..
});
```

You can use this page for future reference :
http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 0):

If your site is `abc.com`, then in simple terms, `/` means the when somebody is coming to your site and he places `abc.com` in browser then execute the following function.

url is relative, so `/` means root.

`.render('index'...` means that render the `index.html` or `index.ejs` that you would be having in your project. Rendering means that send it in the response to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Node is great, but this is one of their few absolutely horrid APIs.

`app.get()` with a single String argument gets a property previously set via `set().`  Basic getter / setter stuff.

`app.get()` with a String and a function means when they do an HTTP GET to this path, call this function.

Bad bad overloading.

Comment: Note that this "absolutely horrid API" is not node but express, and comes from ruby's Sinatra AFAIK. There are plenty of clones in a lot of languages.

Comment: @Darkhogg  thanks for the clarification.  I knew it was really Express (should have been clearer in the answer) but didn't know it came from Sinatra.  So Ol' Blue Eyes is to blame - too much Jack Daniels?